How long are credentials stored in a browser's cache when using express-basic-auth?
I'm using the express-basic-auth library to protect a route in my Express.js application. I want to ensure that the user's credentials are not stored in the browser's cache. Here's the code snippet I'm using:
const express = require('express');
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('./logger');
const app = express();

function myAuthorizer(username, password) {
  try {
    const userMatches = basicAuth.safeCompare(username, 'admin');
    const passwordMatches = basicAuth.safeCompare(password, 'amin');
    return userMatches && passwordMatches;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('myAuthorizer', error);
  }
}

app.use(
  `/${routesPrefix}/v1/readme`,
  basicAuth({
    authorizer: myAuthorizer,
    challenge: true
  }),
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/readme'))
);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});


Question :-

How long are credentials typically stored in a browser's cache when using HTTP Basic Authentication?
Is there a way to prevent the browser from caching these credentials using the express-basic-auth library or any other method?

I understand that the browser usually caches these credentials for the duration of the session, but I want to make sure the credentials are not cached at all.

Isn't this similar to the question you asked yesterday?

Yes, it is similar to the question I asked yesterday, but I still have some uncertainties. Specifically, I'm trying to understand how long credentials are typically stored in a browser's cache when using HTTP Basic Authentication and if there's a way to prevent this caching behavior using the express-basic-auth library or any other method. I'm looking for more detailed information or alternative solutions to ensure user credentials are not cached in the browser.

I want to know if credentials are stored in the browser's cache, what is their default expiration time?

Here is what the specification says in RFC 7235:

Existing HTTP clients and user agents typically retain authentication
information indefinitely.  HTTP does not provide a mechanism for the
origin server to direct clients to discard these cached credentials,
since the protocol has no awareness of how credentials are obtained
or managed by the user agent.  The mechanisms for expiring or
revoking credentials can be specified as part of an authentication
scheme definition.
Circumstances under which credential caching can interfere with the
application's security model include but are not limited to:

Clients that have been idle for an extended period, following
which the server might wish to cause the client to re-prompt the
user for credentials.

Applications that include a session termination indication (such
as a "logout" or "commit" button on a page) after which the server
side of the application "knows" that there is no further reason
for the client to retain the credentials.


User agents that cache credentials are encouraged to provide a
readily accessible mechanism for discarding cached credentials under
user control.

So there's no way for the server to force the client to discard cached credentials, other than by sending a 401 error to indicate that the given credentials are incorrect (as is typically done when the user logs out of the application -- see How to log out from basicAuth (Express))
